# Problems with pinch zoom on Android

Tags: android

I recently discovered a bit of code to keep the backgrounds stable, when pinch zooming on iphone/ipad.
However I am running test on my website on my Android, and when I pinch zoom, the background image, which covers the whole site in the body tag, jumps all over the place.
So is there any code that can counteract this on Android devices, so my website can behave at an acceptable standard?